# custom-validator validate object keys

Tags: typescript, nestjs, customvalidator

I build nestjs with a typescript project and I'm trying to validate filters query params.
I want only filter keys and values can pass validation.
example for good params: pass validation

```
any-endpoint?filters={"userIds"=["1","2","5"],"ages"=[25]}

any-endpoint?filters={"names"=["david","samuel"],"ages"=[21]}
```

example for bad params: failed validation

```
any-endpoint?filters={"blaBla"=["1","2","5"],"ages"=[25]} // here the key blaBla not one of the filters options

any-endpoint?filters={"names"=[1,2]} // here the values of names is not string, it should be string
```

my code

```
import { IsNumber, IsOptional,IsArray, IsString } from 'class-validator';

class FiltersOptionsDto {
  @IsOptional()
  @IsArray()
  @IsString({ each: true })
  userIds?: string[];

  @IsOptional()
  @IsArray()
  @IsString({ each: true })
  ages?: number[];

  @IsOptional()
  @IsArray()
  @IsNumber({}, { each: true })
  names?: string[];
}

export class AQueryDto {
  @IsOptional()
  // what to add here?
  filters?: FiltersOptionsDto;
}
```

how to do it?

Comment: I think you can handle it by using the built in ValidationPipe flag `whitelist`:
https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/validation#using-the-built-in-validationpipe
https://github.com/typestack/class-validator#whitelisting

Comment: The bounty reason as stated "reputable source" might actually reduce your chances "for an answer to this question". If you want "any answer", then the reason "for drawing more attention" would have been better I think. Now I recommend to explain very clearly, whether you really only want answer from reputable source or are happy with any answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All right, so if you really want to send a query in that format, you can use the `@Transform()` decorator from `class-transformer` and use `plainToClass` to transform the filters value. To do this though, you need a couple of things.

1. The `@ValidateNested()` decorator is necessary to make sure that it can be validated as expected. Namely so the child object can be validated.
2. The `@Transform()` decorator will need to be used. This is working for me

```
import { IsOptional, ValidateNested } from 'class-validator';
import { Transform, plainToClass } from 'class-transformer'
import { FiltersOptionsDto } from './filter.dto';

export class AQueryDto {
  @IsOptional()
  @ValidateNested()
  @Transform((value) =>  plainToClass(FiltersOptionsDto, JSON.parse(value.replace(/=/g, ':'))))
  filters?: FiltersOptionsDto;
}
```

Each `=` needs to be made to a `:` so that it is the correct JSON format (I also separated out the classes as I prefer one class per file). With the above, the value passes in to `filters` will be taken from a string value to a JSON (plain), and then from a plain to a class.

3. You need to set `forbidNonWhitelisted: true` in your `ValidationPipe`. I've done this like so:

```
@Module({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_PIPE,
      useValue: new ValidationPipe({ forbidNonWhitelisted: true })
    }
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

(Along with the other providers and controllers of course). I also like to add `transform: true` so that it's no longer JSON or string, but an actual class.

Now you can pass in

```
?filters={"userIds"=["1","2","5"],"ages"=["25"]}
```

And it will succeed while trying to pass in

```
?filters={"blaBla"=["1","2","5"],"ages"=[25]}
```

It will fail.

Answer (score -1):

Haven't tested it, but from the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/class-validator#validating-nested-objects) I figure this is what you need:

```
export class AQueryDto {
  @IsOptional()
  @ValidateNested() // +
  filters?: FiltersOptionsDto;
}
```

Comment: I tried it, not working. it does not validate if the key is one of the filters

Comment: @Manspof Have you tried `validate(query, { whitelist: true, forbidNonWhitelisted: true })` and `@ValidateNested()` at the same time?